# Get request status best practice

Tags: node.js, angular, httprequest

In my Node.js backend, I used to add a boolean in my response to check if everything went good:

```
if(req.body.user.username == null || req.body.user.username == '' || req.body.user.password == null || req.body.user.password == '' || req.body.user.email == null || req.body.user.email == ''){
    res.json({success: false, message: 'Ensure username, email and password provided.'});
  }else{
    user.save((err) => {
      if(err) {
        res.json({success: false, message: 'Username or Email already exists.'});
      }else{
        res.json({success: true, message: 'User created!',user :user});
      }
    });
  }
```

And then, check this variable in my front like this:

```
userRegister(body) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.post("/api/register", body, options).map((res: Response) => res.json())
  }

 register(){
    //make JSON body
    let body = JSON.stringify({"user" : this.registeredUser})
    // Access the USER Service's Auth() method we defined
    this._userService.userRegister(body).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      if(res.success){
        //gotoprofile
      }
    }
 }
```

I've been told that it's a bad practice and I could get the response status code instead. I don't want to use Observables or Promises because it would mean I'll have to implement again every requests.

I tried to get status like this:

```
return this._http.post("/api/register", body, options).map((res: Response, status) => res.json())
```

But it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

As Shown in your code it is posted request. and you can use following standard status code.

```
if(req.body.user.username == null || req.body.user.username == '' || req.body.user.password == null || req.body.user.password == '' || req.body.user.email == null || req.body.user.email == ''){
    res.status(400).json({success: false, message: 'Ensure username, email and password provided.',reason:"Bad Request"});
  }else{
    user.save((err) => {
      if(err) {
        res.status(409).json({success: false, message: 'Username or Email already exists.',reason:"Conflict"});
      }else{
        res.status(201).json({success: true, message: 'User created!',user :user});
      }
    });
  }
```